# Define a TypeScript class based on recursive generic interface

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I'm setting up a base datastructure for a project, hoping to have an abstract `GraphNode` base object from which many other objects will inherit. Each GraphNode subclass has metadata that could include both literals (string, numbers, ...) and references to other GraphNode-derived types.

**Example subclasses:**

```js
interface IPerson {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  friend: Person;
  pet: Pet;
}

interface IPet {
  type: 'dog' | 'cat';
  name: string;
}

class Person extends GraphNode<IPerson> {}
class Pet extends GraphNode<IPet> {}
```

**Example usage:**

```js
const spot = new Pet()
  .set('type', 'dog')
  .set('name', 'Spot');

const jo = new Person()
  .set('name', 'Jo')
  .set('age', 41)
  .set('pet', spot) // ⚠️ Should not accept GraphNode argument.
  .setRef('pet', spot); // ✅ Correct.

const sam = new Person()
  .set('name', 'Sam')
  .set('age', 45)
  .set('friend', jo) // ⚠️ Should not accept GraphNode argument.
  .setRef('friend', jo); // ✅ Correct.
```

My problem is this — how can I define the GraphNode base class, when its generic types depend recursively on the GraphNode class? Here's my attempt:

**Utility Types:**

```js
type Literal = null | boolean | number | string;

type LiteralAttributes<Base> = {
    [Key in keyof Base]: Base[Key] extends Literal ? Base[Key] : never;
};

// ⚠️ ERROR — Generic type 'GraphNode<Attributes>' requires 1 type argument(s).
type RefAttributes<Base> = {
    [Key in keyof Base]: Base[Key] extends infer Child
        ? Child extends GraphNode | null
            ? Child | null
            : never
        : never;
};
```

**Abstract Graph Definition:**

```js
type GraphAttributes = {[key: string]: Literal | GraphNode | null};

abstract class GraphNode<Attributes extends GraphAttributes> {
  public attributes = {} as LiteralAttributes<Attributes> | RefAttributes<Attributes>;

  public get<K extends keyof LiteralAttributes<Attributes>>(key: K): Attributes[K] {
    return this.attributes[key]; // ⚠️ Missing type information.
  }

  public set<K extends keyof LiteralAttributes<Attributes>>(key: K, value: Attributes[K]): this {
    this.attributes[key] = value;
    return this;
  }

  public getRef<K extends keyof RefAttributes<Attributes>>(key: K): Attributes[K] | null {
    return this.attributes[key]; // ⚠️ Missing type information.
  }

  public setRef<K extends keyof RefAttributes<Attributes>>(key: K, value: Attributes[K] | null): this {
    this.attributes[key] = value; // ⚠️ Missing type information.
    return this;
  }
}
```

That doesn't compile, and I've flagged the TS errors in comments above. I think that comes down to a basic problem – I want to extend the generic class later, with type arguments that *refer to the generic class*, and I'm not sure how to do that. I could live with not having strict type checking within the GraphNode class itself, but I really do want its subclasses to have strict type checking.

I've also created an [example TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKj4yumFgCgAEJEFUAuBLANp9BPRAFXwAcBTAZwDoFlgEECLEAZPcgJwENtEBeRADsArtj4AfRACMA9rOzluQxFNEBbaV1WJK6TpiEBzANyN4zcmw49sAQXT7M0keioAeAELdK5AHwCiADeCACQANoA0uSEhogA1jGyAGaI3r4AugBcaT7kUTEZiOQAHm5CACaU1m62iAD8ub4F+EU5QuQAblxm8AC+vQjAwIiABWSA8H+IAKIASjMA8jOIgCgEiADi5B0GAMaIlogA5Gs8pAAWAHKyFeTuDk4ubpR+B4ic5ACOIphv1QCMe2QrNxOEYROpNugABSUACUtAsgMQM3IyTuBgeHnS-kCIXgEWisRUiXwKSa5GyZJaRVK5SqiEMyW0AGFTjgKmFQo0WWzimVNnTjtwzpdrjpROIOZzENzsBUxWJsJL2l0uBzld1OL0BuZQDA9fq4EgUHZpHoeNt0OsTqdEAARFGGPCYWRCeH0cz7QVnNHOVxUHHhYk5M2GIwU9i1Xg6L0XK5WNQK7XwBDcU36bgWxDbbA+aoxkU3H0Y6o0-l561Fv1PYJ0RCkETSXC7biOdFVnF9RA+GpcXiVx63Vu+x4BKTI1FD4uD+5VvyDJB1htNxBGcjodyRXm06rE0kR3v2SdV6dtkd+SFBxCRGE5ftUKJFXGIZ+vNciTgqdCsmgtmePQOFCYiDDGMkwALKYJQlChgCLAMrInDqC2zqurWfTmM+9aNpguy+Oum6lpUO5JKk+62HelAnsOVB+Oel6RAANIgnS8CI5C3ke-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) reproducing this code with the compiler errors.

Comment: There's quite a bit going on here; is this a [mre] (emphasis on *minimal*)?  Why do some of `LiteralAttributes<T>`'s properties have type `never`?  Do you expect `attributes` to hold values of type `never`?  Why is `attributes` a union type instead of an intersection? Do you expect `attributes` to *either* hold the literal attributes of `A` *or* the ref attributes of `A` instead of *both*? I might be able to refactor this into something that compiles, but I wish this example were pared down further.  I'll keep looking.

Comment: Oh, uh, you are using `null` instead of `undefined`... is there a reason for that?  When I call `get()` or `getRef()` and the value is not in `attributes` you're going to get `undefined` out no matter what.  But you don't seem to be accounting for that at all.  What's your plan here?

Comment: Hi @jcalz – thanks for your reply! I'll see if I can reduce it further. I do expect `attributes` to hold a mix of literal attributes of A _and_ ref attributes of A. I've just found a [relevant issue on TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40315), and depending on how I set this up it can hit that error. I'm not so worried about the `null` vs `undefined` part, and was trying to gloss over it here since I think I'd know how to solve it later.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Ndd8nN) meet your needs?  If so I can maybe write up an answer.  The problem with having example code with unrelated issues is that it's distracting; if `null` vs `undefined` isn't something you're asking about, then it has the potential to derail the conversation.  Anyway, if the linked approach doesn't work for some use case please let me know (and preferably [edit] the example to demonstrate the unsatisfied use case).

Comment: I'll do some further testing but I think that does solve my question – thank you! I posted an additional playground link in an edit above, with a possible solution of my own, but yours looks cleaner. Could you explain what the `-?` part of the syntax does?

Comment: It's a [mapping modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) to make optional properties required and removing `undefined` from the domain of the property value.  Otherwise sometimes `LiteralKeys<T>` might return something like `"a" | "b" | undefined`.  If you have your own solution it should probably go as an answer and not a modification to the question.  I will probably write up an answer when I get some time today.

Comment: Oh I see, it's "too long for a comment".  You might be interested in https://tsplay.dev which is what I use to put my playground links in comments

Comment: @jcalz there is also a plugin in ts playground for url shortening

Comment: Yes, I use that plugin, but telling people how to enable it is a bit less clear than just using the tsplay.dev url which is the same thing.

Comment: @jcalz – Your solution is working, I'm glad to accept an answer when you have the chance to write it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are quite a few issues in the original code which made it not behave the way you want.  First, to get the keys of an object type `T` whose values are assignable to a type `V`, you can do something like this:

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> = {[K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never}[keyof T];
```

This [maps](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) the properties from `T` to either the key `K` or `never` [depending on whether or not](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) whether those properties are assignable to `V`, and then immediately [indexes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into that mapped type with `keyof T` to get the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of keys we care about.

We can specialize that to get the keys of `T` whose properties are assignable to `Literal` and those whose properties are assignable to some `GraphNode<X>` type:

```
type LiteralKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends Literal ? K : never }[keyof T];
type RefKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends GraphNode<any> ? K : never }[keyof T]
```

So we can use `LiteralKeys<A>` instead of your `keyof LiteralAttributes<A>` which didn't work because `keyof LiteralAttributes<A>` is always the same as `keyof A` (you were mapping the bad property values to `never` but that doesn't eliminate the key).

---

Now `GraphNode` can be defined like this:

```
abstract class GraphNode<A extends Record<keyof A, Literal | GraphNode<any>>> {
  public attributes: Partial<A> = {};

  public get<K extends LiteralKeys<A>>(key: K): A[K] | undefined {
    return this.attributes[key];
  }

  public set<K extends LiteralKeys<A>>(key: K, value: A[K]): this {
    this.attributes[key] = value;
    return this;
  }

  public getRef<K extends RefKeys<A>>(key: K): A[K] | undefined {
    return this.attributes[key];
  }

  public setRef<K extends RefKeys<A>>(key: K, value: A[K] | undefined): this {
    this.attributes[key] = value;
    return this;
  }
}
```

Note that you `GraphNode<A>` is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type parameter `A`, and whenever you refer to `GraphNode` you must specify the generic type parameter.  You can't just say `GraphNode`. If you don't know or care what the type parameter should be, you can use [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any), like `GraphNode<any>`.  This will always work, but may end up allowing some things you don't want to allow.  In this case it's probably fine.

`A` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Record<keyof A, Literal | GraphNode<any>>` instead of `{[k: string]: Literal | GraphNode<any>}` because we don't really want to require that `A` have a `string` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).  By constraining `A` to `Record<keyof A, ...>` we are saying the keys can be whatever they happen to be.

The `attributes` property is of type `Partial<A>`.  It's `A` because we want to hold something very much like `A` and not anything like `LiteralAttributes<A> | RefAttributes<A>`.  And we're using the [`Partial<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) to acknowledge that at any given time it might not have all of the properties of `A` set; indeed it is initialized as `{}`, which has no properties at all.  This also means I have changed the `get()` and `getRef()` return types to include `undefined`.

The `get()` and `set()` methods are generic in `K extends LiteralKeys<A>`, while the `getRef()` and `setRef()` methods are generic in `K extends RefKeys<A>`.  For most reasonable `A` types, `LiteralKeys<A>` and `RefKeys<A>` will be mutually exclusive and together make up all of `keyof T`.  If `A` has any properties which are themselves unions or intersections of `Literal` and `GraphNode<any>` then this might not be true.  I'm not worried about this here but if that does happen you can expect to run into some weird edge cases.

---

Let's make sure this behaves the way you want. Your subclasses and usage compile as expected, even resulting in this:

```
const jo = new Person()
  .set('name', 'Jo')
  .set('age', 41)
  .set('pet', spot) // error! Argument of type '"pet"' 
  // is not assignable to parameter of type 'LiteralKeys<IPerson>'
  .setRef('pet', spot); 

const sam = new Person()
  .set('name', 'Sam')
  .set('age', 45)
  .set('friend', jo) // error! Argument of type '"friend"'
  // is not assignable to parameter of type 'LiteralKeys<IPerson>'
  .setRef('friend', jo);
```

So it looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMglsCAnAhgGygXigOwK5oYA+UARgPbloQo5Qn4C2py9UAzsEnDgOYDcAWABQoSLATJ0AaQgh2AHgAqAPixQA3lADa0qDygBrOeQBmUJQF0AtAH4AXBd2WoEAB6IcAE3YTEqDFsoPUccCAA3VgBfbWMQMwtLIVFwaAAlCFNZeWU1bC1dfTo4hKs7RyVnVw8Ib18AcVQwAAsAOXIvCAVaEDUgkNwI6NiTcysRCeEAegAqOfmFxaXllZEoGagAQVJOVABjYChGlBaoABFMngQ4chwAOjWZqcmUHa4UA6g9tBR2Bqa2h0uptqp4fFAMntyEgvAoSuZNgAaPxSYhHAHtTrdHC9FRqDRrKBgPCkNBwPZQFDALhwUh4RDsRwABRQSGAcHQCk2eU0UWShOJpPJUF4EGACj07jBvng-hkckU3JUAAo4o5pABKRybKokPDeS5hLyaQlQKBIMV4JB0YDNODsO5Uml0hkjEBJQlRSZmwVkinsMUS0G1cGy1HZRV41VydXI8LoPAQbXOLVQW32k3CM1m9MOp3cF0QdhulzYeNoRPJbPmy3WtN29hVqBe4QCkl+kVijKmINSkO+bsRrlRtXBVM66QuPUG0w8CDGglZ7MW4BWm0Nx3Ugv0oslpstttC-1dzK9mp1CGZIdK6MgWNQcuJ5OTtj6zqzo2p3OZ6u5zfOndiziUsHwTCAmzNFc13re19xEA9phWJDkKQx4oAAUTcFBGDAagoAASRw6hGFqYAqRue5HmeVthB4fxTA+aB8KZZB2FuH9cGwpMOBpPgmxQUVQjwZhkCbUxuBDZlWNuJtIGAKTgGSBC6OQBi9iYljDkXHNUkcAByLxyF4PS2D0vYqT0pscC4xxdh4AR4Mmb5fl8FikDYug+wvY4WkxLpmOknB8WbERnL+KBNODbyMSBBQAuAYKENmFCUpStCAFV2AEiAHizJ4nNuTgODAchDmwMIAHcIrFZUNUJO4A2AZU9LECA9ORAyjL0uqlwamq9Oskj2qgPSAGUSuAbr+WEKEcCKgArch1Eq6r3NuWr6sa5rBrajqAClyG6zb+uy4aABYAEYerNPqmr0uThvYCaNSgKYplcJAkGhABCLYkF4YTSKgBJWpGgAiOSwZMwk3v0XwcFKyk-jgXhrNJaBgCWsBWS4-xgfMUG9LDAIhwCtagr047gG7ZqHuRJ7So1fgoAKubDiyxhlogKq3I8jbeq2gauOGsbsKOgWTtFc6AFZrqgW7mvEuAQ2GxaXth5AvqQX7Nn+wGcEOEHUnBpWQyhmH3ozBHDhclG0bwzGiRxki8aN8QickEmFTi3nbhUSmJepzJFYk7xVfIJmWeEIA)

Comment: Thanks @jcalz! This solution is working well for me, and I appreciate the thorough explanation and your comments/clarifications along the way.